# Twitter's typeahead + Bloodhound with JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead, bloodhound

I can't get it to work with JSON objects. I've followed multiple questions here on SO and none of the answers helped me.

```
$(function() {
 var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    prefetch: {
        url: 'items.json',
        filter: function(list) {
            return $.map(list, function(item) {
                return {
                    name: item.name,
                    category: item.category,
                    release: item.release,
                    id: item.id
                };
            });
        }
    }
 });

 items.initialize();

 $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'items',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: items.ttAdapter()
 });
});
```

JSON is as:

```
[
 {"id":"4","name":"Name 1","release":"July 28, 2014","category":"Bow"},
 {"id":"1","name":"Name 2","release":"October 29, 2014","category":"Bow"},
 {"id":"13","name":"Name 3","release":"November 27, 2014","category":"Arrow"}
]
```

Comment: use console.log(list) inside prefetch.filter to be sure theres something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it wouldn't work is was because of Typeahead's LocalStorage usage (or perhaps my abuse of it, I guess we'll never know). As soon as I cleared that, it instantly worked.

Comment: you can set `cache` property to false inside setting of Bloohound object, by default its true which let Bloodhound use localStorage for caching the fetched data.